# How to customize emacs auc-tex function Tex-command-list?

Tags: emacs, customization, auctex

I'm trying to use the latex package `nomencl' which allows one to easily create a Nomenclature section in an article. So far so good.

I'm using emacs with AucTeX and I added the nomenclature compile option to the emacs Tex-Command-list by editing my .emacs file, adding:

```
;;nomenclature for latex
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list 
        '("Nomenclature" "makeindex %s.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %s.nls" TeX-run-command nil t :help "Create nomenclature file")))
```

to it, this works: when I press `C-c C-c` (the shortcut for TeX-command-list I can use the `Nomenclature` command and the appropriate file is generated. I am unhappy though, for the following reason:

When I run BibTex (using Tex-Command-list), and then press C-c C-c again, emacs offers to run LaTeX, as appropriate, and if references have changed, it will offer LaTeX again, finally, it will offer View, once the .log doesn't report references have changed.

**However** When I run Nomenclature, the next command offered by Tex-command-list is View, which is alway inappropriate, since one needs to compile again after recreating the nomenclature file.

> How can I tell emacs to give LaTeX as the next TeX-command-list command after running Nomenclature (same behavior as BibTeX)?

Comment: I've also posted this question on Tex.SE, as I'm not sure where is more appropriate.

Comment: I think you're more likely to get help at the TeX SE than here.

Comment: I posted an answer on TeX.SE: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/using-nomenclature-and-emacs

Comment: I've voted to close: it's essentially a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/using-nomenclature-and-emacs - it might be nice to move this qn & then merge with that, since the answers are different enough.

Answer (score 1):

The AUCTeX function `TeX-command-query` is responsible for that.  Right now, it simply checks for the existence of .bbl, .pdf, .ps, .dvi files and guesses the next step.  If Nomenclature also generates some new files that, when present determine that TeX must be run again, it should be easy to add that feature.

Update: The answer on TeX SE is even better. :-)